# Twilio - chained twimlets

Tags: twilio, chained

I would like use the twimlets in a chain in this order. I don't know how to do it.

```
http://twimlets.com/message
http://twimlets.com/forward
http://twimlets.com/voicemail
```

ie. Say a message, forward a call, if no answer, goto voicemail.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

You should be able to do this by using the echo and voicemail Twimlets:

You would use this [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) in the echo Twimlet:

```
<Response>
    <Say>Hold on while we connect you</Say>
    <Dial 
         action="/forward?Dial=true&amp;FailUrl=http://twimlets.com/voicemail?Email=foo%40bar.com&amp;Message=Please%20leave%20a%20message&amp;Transcribe=false&" 
         timeout="20" 
         callerId="555-555-5555">555-555-5555</Dial>
</Response>
```

This TwiML tells Twilio to say a message, then try to dial a phone number.  If the call fails (or no one answers) it forwards to the Voicemail Twimlet.

Devin

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I tried the example in                  https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/echo. when I click the resulting url, I get the error "error on line 4 at column 35: EntityRef: expecting ';'" . Any idea?

Comment: Sorry.  I forgot you have to escape the & characters in the action URL, otherwise its invalid XML.  I changed the snippet.